What is the spectrum of this differential operator?
My self-adjount differential operator  $L$ is defined by $$L f(x) \equiv u(x) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \left( u(x) f(x) \right)$$ where $u(x)$ is a known but arbitrary smooth function that satisfies $u(x) > 0$ $\forall x$.
I seek a basis of eigenfunctions of $L$, and their eigenvalues.
Are there any results known that help with this problem?
Are there any specific forms for $u(x)$ (other than $u\equiv 1$) that make the problem easier?
Edit: I am looking for eigenfunctions that do not explode, and form a useful basis in which I could in principle expand other "well behaved" functions. For example, if $u(x)\equiv 1$ I would select $e^{i\lambda x}$ as eigenfunctions, with eigenvalues $-\lambda^2$.
Edit 2:
In practice, $u(x)$ is a function that is close to $1$. Its shape might be roughly $1$ at $-\infty$ smoothly reducing to $0.5$ at $0$ and back to $1$ at $\infty$.
Edit 3:
As I said it is self-adjoint, I have a specific inner product in mind, namely $<f,g>  = \int dx f(x) g(x)$. In that case, I think we can write $L = - D^T D$. Does this help?

What space of functions...? Any boundary conditions...? Even things that "look" self-adjoint (some people call them "formally self-adjoint") can fail to have any self-adjoint extensions at all, or have infinitely-many, ... Can you clarify?

I have tried to clarify this as best I can.  Thie background is it will help me to solve a related problem numerically, so I am looking for smooth functions that don't explode, but more generally anything that is known about this type of problem

Just for clarity, are there parentheses missing after the derivative?

Yes, thank you, I have now fixed the brackets

if $u(x)=x$, eigenfunctions are $f(x)=x^q$ with eigenvalue $q(q+1)$

I assume the domain is $x\in \mathbb{R}$? Is the function $u$ bounded? Is it bounded away from zero uniformly? If it is allow to approach zero, what is the asymptotic rate?

If it helps any, two smooth $u()$ that satisfy your conditions and might be analyzable are $u(x)=1-\frac1{2(x^2+1)}$ and $u(x)=1-\frac12e^{-x^2}$.

@Willie Wong Yes the domain is the real numbers.  The function u can go to zero roughly linearly as x goes to zero in some cases of interest, and it can go to infinity as x goes to infinity. But I am also interested in the strictly positive and bounded case

With the inner product you mentioned, you are formally looking for critical points of the Rayleigh quotient $ \frac{\int [\partial_x (uf)]^2 ,dx}{\int f^2,dx}$, but be cautious with the integrability and BCs. This gives some intuition on the obvious fact that $1/u$ is an eigenfunction to $\lambda=0$ if this is an admissible function in the game.

Yes 1 / u is certainly admissible

@PeterA: if $u$ vanishes to zero linearly as $x$ tends to zero, then $1/u$ is not square integrable and cannot be an eigenfunction.

@Willie Wong thank you, yes good point. For the purpose of this question we should assume u is always greater than a constant. Better ignore the case where it can go to zero for now. Mistake on my part to introduce it here

Another rather trivial remark: if you substitute $g:=uf$ you end up with an equation $g''=u^{-2}\lambda g$, which is in a standard Sturm-Liouville format. Finding explicit solutions will very much depend on the specific choice of $u$.

Ironically, that is exactly my original form. I scaled by u to get a self adjoint operator, which I thought would make it easier
